# WordPress : Redirection Plugin Not Working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am currently working on redirections.

The first thing I tried was putting a line of code in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.new-site.com/
```

It works in Chrome and Internet Explorer but does not work in Firefox. So I decided to use a plugin. I used **Redirection Plugin**. It was working in my other site. When I used it in another site, it works in random browsers. It works on my Chrome but Chrome on other PC does not work.

Some PC when accessed with `http://www.new-site.com/index.html`, it shows a 403 Error. I just don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a little tip to save you time – you do not need to enter your site's domain in the "Source URL" box – just the extension. Let's say your site was `http://www.domain/` and you wanted to redirect the URL: `http://www.domain/myurl/`. In order to set up the redirect, you only need to type in `/myurl/` in the "Source URL" box – the plugin will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found the cause: I was trying to redirect `/ads.txt` to `https://example.com`, but I forgot to delete the existing `ads.txt` file on my server (at `/var/www/html/ads.txt`, in my case), and so Apache was serving that directly rather than sending the request along to wordpress.